# Diameter of Schreier coset graphs.

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, book-recommendation, algebraic-graph-theory

I'm looking for a source from which to learn about [Schreier coset graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreier_coset_graph). Especially, examples in which combinatorial properties (specifically, diameter) of Schreier graphs are calculated.

Also, is there an english translation of Schreier's work: "[Die Untergruppen der freien Gruppen](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02952517)"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper (Annexstein, Baumslag and Rosenberg, "Group action graphs and parallel architectures", SIAM Journal on Computing, pp. 544-569, 1990) studies various properties of coset graphs - including diameter - that arise in network contexts.  In that paper, Schreier coset graphs are called [Cayley] coset graphs.  The coset graph of $G$ with respect to a subgroup $H$ and a subset $S$ is denoted $Cos(G,H,S)$.

Not every vertex-transitive graph can be realized as a Cayley graph (the Petersen graph is the usual counterexample).  But every vertex-transitive graph can be realized as a coset graph.  This was proved by (Sabidussi, "Vertex-transitive graphs", 1964).

It is mentioned in (Heydemann, "Cayley graphs and interconnection networks", in Graph Symmetry: Algebraic Methods and Applications, Eds. Hahn and Sabidussi, p. 189) that coset graphs have been used in constructing graphs for the degree/diameter problem.